# IdentityServer4 external logout doesn't remove Google sign-on cookie

Tags: cookies, identityserver4

I am having trouble logging out of my identityServer under Google login. I can login through Google (external) with no issues but the logout never worked. After clicking on "Logout" I always get a message says "you are now logged out". But when I try to log back in again, I always get right in after clicking on the Googol button. My Chrome's Dev Tool shows that a cookie associated with my Google login left in there regardless if I click on logout.

[image]

And if I clear the cookie via Chrome, I will be able to get to the Google login page.

In trying to delete the cookie in my program when logging out, I tried the following code from the AccountController's Logout function. I watched the code got executed in debug mode, but it doesn't make any difference - the cookie is still there after the code gets executed and I am still get right in.

Could anyone tell me what I am missing here? Or is it just impossible to delete cookie from code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do an upstream signout the IDP (Google) would have to support the RP-initiated logout spec:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout

However Google's discovery endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) does not advertise an `end_session_endpoint` so from that we'd have to conclude that it is not supported by Google.

*However* you may be able to use `prompt=login` or `max_age={number of seconds}` in your `authorization_endpoint` endpoint request to force interactive authentication again. When you receive the `id_token` in the callback you can validate that the `auth_time` claim falls within whatever condition you decide. The end result is that you can insist that users interactively authenticate each time you do a round trip to Google. If `auth_time` is too far in the past you'd prevent the local session from being established.

Comment: Thank you @mackie! I think I understand that Google doesn't support upstream signout. But I thought my issue was local, not with Google, not about upstream signout, because it is my cookie that could not be deleted. And if I clear the cookie manually, I am fine. Are you saying that the reason why the cookie cannot be deleted by my code is because that Google doesn't support it? I am a little confused here. Please excuse my ignorance, I am fairly new on these stuff still

Comment: Correct - you can't remove Google's auth cookie via your IDP without Google supporting the above spec as there's no way of you manipulating a cookie directly for another origin. The workaround lets you force them to sign in again even if they don't strictly speaking have to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @mackie! But the workaround will work the same regardless if logout is called, correct?

Comment: Assuming Google respect the parameters mentioned, yes. The chances of that a high though as both `prompt` and `max_age` are part of the core OIDC spec.